# Map Ranges of Font Sizes for Mobile With CSS

Tags: css, mobile, sass, responsive-design, font-size

Problems:

- Bigger font sizes look fine on desktop, but are too large on mobile
- The font sizes are user-defined from a rich text editor, so it's harder to cover every case with individual media queries
- The aim is for bigger font sizes to map to smaller sizes on mobile

  - But smaller font sizes should not be mapped to even smaller sizes (for sake of readability)
- I can achieve something like this with rem-based content and modifying the `:root` font-size on mobile screen sizes, but it obviously affects every size. I'm trying to see if I can just affect font-sizes over a certain threshold.

Example of what I've done so far:

```
<p style="5.5rem">User-styled text</p>

:root {
    font-size: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    :root {
        font-size: 6px;
    }
}
```

As mentioned, this only solves half the problem (big sizes, not smaller ones).

The goal is a mapping that looks something like this:

```
Desktop -> Mobile
 73-100 -> 50
  65-72 -> 45
  56-64 -> 40
  35-55 -> 35
   8-34 -> Don't touch
```

Not sure if this is possible in CSS (or sass/less), but I'm open to ideas, even if it doesn't strictly match the criteria (i.e. close enough). Wanting to avoid JS if possible and a sweeping rule would be better than a per-element treatment.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this [calculator](https://websemantics.uk/tools/responsive-font-calculator/)

```css
@media (min-width: 30rem) {
  :root {
    font-size: calc(1rem + ((1vw - 0.3rem) * 1.1111));
  }
}

@media (min-width: 120rem) {
  :root {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>The root font size scales up and down proportionately, between defined values, dependent upon the viewport width.
</p>
```